# How to read multiple levels of JSON file through Python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I am trying to read a JSON file where the data are at various level, i.e. Top --> inner --> inner most.

I have tried the `pd.json_normalization`, but I don't think it is working. I have attached a screenshot. In that the top most level is `"WTFY_Combined"`, and inside it there are three more levels of data. So, out of the levels, I need to read "OccuMa" which is marked in yellow color, and then inside "OccuMa", there are another level of data "OccuCode" and "OccuDesc". I need to read those two levels in two different dataframes.
I know that one way of doing is to take those two in two different JSON files, but in real, I will have such multi level structure to read.

I am trying below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json as js

with open ("filepath", "r") as f:
   data = js.loads(f.read())
df_flat = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['OccuCode'])
df_flat2 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['OccuDesc'])
```

But, it is not working, its giving `"keyerror"` for obvious reason that I am not able to map the data into the dataframe properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json as js

with open ("filepath", "r") as f:
    json_data = js.loads(f.read())

json_data  = json_data['WTYF_Combined']['Extraction']['abc']['OccuMa']
df_data = pd.DataFrame(json_data)[['OccuCode','OccuDesc']]
```

Comment: am still getting KeyError: 'OccuMa'.

Comment: "Ian, that extra 'abc' was missing. Adding that, fixed the issue. thanks